# Find the co-ordinates within selected rectangle in openlayer map

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I have drawn some points on openlayer map based on geo position co-ordinates, now I will draw rectangle on the map,now I need to get all my co-ordinates within my rectangle

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html

I need to get my drawn positions within rectangle

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to handle the DRAWEND event of ol.interaction.Draw and retrieve all features with `vector.getSource().getFeatures()`. Iterating through the features gives you the point geometries and the rectangle geometry. With rectangleGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(pointCoordinate) you can check if the point is inside the rectangle.